# No questions asked when installing Django CMS - so no bootstrap

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-cms

I installed Django CMS through Powershell using the command:
    `pip install djangocms-installer`

I'm new to this, and the tutorial that I've been following suggested that I should be asked questions to set up Bootstrap and the SuperUser account. These questions weren't asked. Does anybody know why and how I could change this by hand? The django docs don't seem to be much help here because they assume that the questions are asked.

It occurs when I create a new project using:

```
djangocms -p . project
```

It just runs through rather than asking questions - no errors to report

Comment: Please improve your question are post the error you got while installing/running the process for analysis and better response.

Comment: I don't get an error, it just runs through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this helps but I had all sorts of headaches the first time I tried to install Django-cms.  After much head scratching I did get it to successfully install and I was able to get up and running with it.  I also created a crib sheet along the way of all the steps I took.

I have published this crib sheet on my website and you are welcome to go and review it, print it off etc. It will take you right back to the very beginning which may be unnecessary but hopefully you might be able to cherry pick the bits that you need.  Hope it helps.

http://www.ubsltd.co.uk/index.php/creating-a-cms-website-with-django

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look over. I found that the issue is because of updates since this book was released. The command is now `djangocms -w -p [path] [project name]` I'll give your link a look because it may be more up to date